# __SoapClient - SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'auth' property

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

When I call the function `__SoapClient` it results with  `"object has no 'auth' property"` error. Below is the code:

What am I missing?

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://api.example.com/ws/ProductStockService.wsdl");
$sonuc = $client->__soapCall('UpdateStockByCode',$postData);
```

And here content of `$postData` array when I `echo` it:

```
Array
(
    [auth] => Array
        (
            [appKey] => 4f9114b1db42
            [appSecret] => jfgi6HYce
        )

    [stockItems] => Array
        (
            [stockItem] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [sellerStockCode] => TIST460974XL
                            [quantity] => 0
                            [version] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```